# CTI plugin as separate window need to be focused/maximized on event

Tags: cti

I have CTI plugin in salesforce that should be focused/maximized on event. It's OK  when CTI is in same window, you can just call *sforce.interaction.setVisible(true);*  but when it's in separate browser window(it's when click pop up icon) there is no API that allows it.

[image]